# Find the matrix of the rotation matrix $U$

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products, rotations, orthogonal-matrices

> The matrix of $U$ in $\mathbb{R^3}$,with the standard inner product which is rotation of the plane $W=sp\{\alpha_1,\alpha_2\}$ about the orthogonal line $\alpha_3$ through the angle $\theta$ , where $\alpha_1,\alpha_2$ are orthonormal basis of $W$ and $\alpha_3$ is the vector of norm $1$ which is orthogonal to $W$.

Since $\alpha_3$ is a vector of norm $1$ and the matrix of rotation is about the line $sp\{\alpha_3\}$.

Then, $U(\alpha_3)=\alpha_3$.

Also,$U(\alpha_1)=cos(\theta).\alpha_1-sin(\theta).(\alpha_2)+0.\alpha_3$.

$U(\alpha_2)=sin(\theta).\alpha_1+cos(\theta).\alpha_2+0.\alpha_3$

Although, I cant reason out the last two equations but this is whatmy intuition.I need help after this.

Comment: It might help to find the image of the 3 unit vectors.